# Motorcycle front brake's are weak

Tags: motorcycle

A few weeks ago I was in a motorcycle accident and my handlebar had bent and so had my old brake lever. A buddy of mine who's quite good with motorcycle's bent the bar back and changed the brake lever. Since than the front brake makes a clicking sound when applied and it's extremely weak! Could air have gotten in the system? What could be the problem here?

Comment: If you need assistance please post a short video of the issue you are experiencing.  Pulling the lever with the clicking sound would work well.  You do probably have air in your brakes.  Also, make/model/year of the motorcycle.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good chance that air got into your system when the motorcycle was on it's side.

You will need to bleed the air out of your brakes.

Comment: If it hasn't been done in a while, you should probably completely flush out the old fluid with new.  You'll probably flush it all in the process of bleeding anyway.

Comment: Might also be worth now checking the thickness and state of the brake disc and friction pads on the brake pads, running the brakes while they are poorly maintained may have affected their ability to stop the bike correctly when the air is bled out of the system.